# How to prevent inheritance of static methods?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static

I have a base class `X`, which has a static method `setDB( $db )`, which accepts the database connection to be used by all its instantiated subclasses.

Everything works as expected.

Now I have a class `Y`, which extends `X`. When I type its class name (`Y::` in this case), my autocompletion shows `Y::setDB()` as an option. It seems to be inherited from its parent class.

Is there a way to make the static method only available in the base class and not in the child class?

Comment: Methods are inherited from their parents, yes. That's how inheritance works.

Comment: Of course I understand that they are inherited. That is why I ask the question whether it is possible to inherit only specific methods and not all of them. The `final` keyword does not seem to solve my question

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm, With `final`, it cannot be extended in the child class, but it is still available to call

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm And `final` [helps with neither](https://3v4l.org/RUIbA). A `final` method is both being inherited *and* callable.